# Rails. Large vendor.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, asset-pipeline, assets

I have vendor.js file in my rails project containing several vendor libraries altogether and after adding some new libraries I'm facing into this problem in development environment

```
Started GET "/assets/vendor.js" for 10.40.129.65 at 2013-03-03 14:01:24 +0400
Cache write: 0d6281da1957dd9c5e063fb636c50bd260dae5e2
Cache read: 0d6281da1957dd9c5e063fb636c50bd260dae5e2
Cache read: http://work:3000/assets/vendor.js?
Cache write: http://work:3000/assets/vendor.js?
!! Rack application returned nil body. Probably you wanted it to be an empty string?
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Trying to remove some libraries fixes the issue and precompiled assets works fine. But I want to make it work in development. Help me please.

vendor.js:

```
//= require ./vendor/ext/stacktrace.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require js_notifier
//= require ./vendor/ext/mustache-1.4.2
//= require ./vendor/ext/strftime
//= require ./vendor/ext/moment
//= require ./vendor/ext/langs.js
//= require ./vendor/ext/jquery.jgrowl_minimized.js
//= require ./vendor/ext/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js
//= require ./vendor/ext/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js
//= require ./vendor/ext/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js
//= require ./vendor/ext/backbone.paginator.js
//= require ./vendor/ext/jquery-deparam.min.js
//= require ./vendor/ext/select2.js
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require ./vendor/channels.js.coffee
//= require ./vendor/ext/bootstrap.switch.js
//= require ./vendor/ext/private_pub
//= require ./vendor/ext/spin.js
//= require ./vendor/ext/jquery.spin.js
```

I'm using Memcached + Dalli

UPD:
I've set cache_store in every environment explicitly (developemnt.rb, production.rb and test.rb) and this fixed the issue until I opened Google Chrome for which the issue raised again. As a result, in FF everything works fine and Chrome fails to load vendor.js (the same server instance (thin) and in the same time for both browsers)

log for ff request:

```
Cache read: http://work:3000/assets/vendor.js?
Cache read: 577d6ed0d98975b583329c312bd25667620f2497
```

log for chrome request (same as above):

```
Started GET "/assets/vendor.js" for 10.40.129.65 at 2013-03-03 20:37:11 +0400
Cache write: 577d6ed0d98975b583329c312bd25667620f2497
Cache read: 577d6ed0d98975b583329c312bd25667620f2497
Cache read: http://work:3000/assets/vendor.js?
Cache write: http://work:3000/assets/vendor.js?
!! Rack application returned nil body. Probably you wanted it to be an empty string?
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: what's your cache store?

Comment: what's your `config.cache_store`

Comment: config.cache_store = Rails.env.test? ? :null_store : :dalli_store

Comment: `!! Rack application returned nil body. Probably you wanted it to be an empty string?` usually happens with `null_store`

Comment: I have changed cache store to
`config.cache_store = :dalli_store`
and it seems to work, but why it trying to use null_store in development environment?

Comment: and are you sure it's not changed in another config file?

Comment: please look at the updated topic, your advice helps partially

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to apply `index.js` technique , as described in [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) (2.1.2). Try to split your big file and include the parts in a manifest file , for example:

In your `/app/vendor/assets/javascripts` you create a new directory `my_libraries` and place parts in it . Then in the same directory you create `index.js` manifest file and include files as normal:

```
//= require file1
//= require file2
```

and in your `application.js` :

```
//= require my_libraries
```

EDIT: One solution would be : in your `/vendor/ext` (the correct path is `app/vendor/assets/javascripts/ext`, if you have a path like `/vendor/ext` it will not be clear it is meant to be managed as asset dir , and also it will not be clear what asset you include - js or css) to create `index.js` with content:

```
//= require_tree .
```

and in `application.js` :

```
//= require ext
```

and then you should remove all the references to `vendor` dir from your `application.js` manifest . Another mistake is including files in your manifest with `.js` prefix. In the manifest file you should state inclusions without prefix.

Take a look at the asset-pipeline's documentation explaining the `require_tree` usage.

Comment: No, vendor.js locates in app/assets/javascript/. After all this solution works great if I remove some libraries from vendor.js (e.g. EJS templates)